# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer delays UIButtons events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I ran into a pretty annoying issue here involving `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`and `UIButton` interactions.

**Here the context:** I am developing an Ipad app. The `view` of my `UIViewController` contains a lot of `UIButton`'s both at its very top and bottom. I realized after a while that, when being pressed at specific location, the `UIButton`'s weren't behaving as usual. Taking the top row as an example, when the button is pressed at a location really close from the edge of the screen, the event linked to that button would take around .5 second to be triggered. I can also visually see it as the button takes time to be highlighted.

**What the cause is:** I did a bit of research and from what I could read from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046539/uibutton-fails-to-properly-register-touch-in-bottom-region-of-iphone-screen) there is apparently a *"conflict between the possibility of a gesture directed at your app and a gesture directed at the system"*. Basically as the user tap near the edges of the screen, the device is waiting for the user to swipe down or up (using `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, for example) and that is most likely why I get this delay with my `UIButton`'s.

**Now:** All the posts regarding this issue are a little bit outdated. I tried different work-around and "not-that-convenient" solution:

i.e. Subclassing my `UIButton`'s  to allow the touch to "bypass"  `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` with the following method:

```
-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    BOOL pointInside = [super pointInside: point withEvent: event];
    for (UIButton *view in self.subviews) {

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point)) pointInside = YES;

            return pointInside;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

But in vain, still doesn't fix the issue.

I am wondering if anyone came up with an easy solution to that ? Or maybe Apple did a fix ?
Any suggestions / solutions / comments would be greatly appreciated folks!