# Part of UIScrollView doesn't respond to touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIScrollView` with 7 `UIButton`s on it.

5 buttons are working fine but the other two (which the scroll view needs to be scrolled for the buttons to be reached) doesn't work most of the times (if I tap a lot of times they sometimes work but most of the time they don't).

I've tried to increase the `contentSize` and the buttons still don't work.

I've tried to change the x position of the buttons and they both work so the problem is definitely about the position in the scrollView.

**Code:**

scrollView:

```
self.buttonsScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.bounds)
self.buttonsScrollView?.frame.origin.y = (self.window?.frame.size.height)! - self.bounds.size.height
self.buttonsScrollView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
self.buttonsScrollView?.canCancelContentTouches = true
self.buttonsScrollView?.clipsToBounds = false
```

buttons (x7)

```
let buttonX = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: previousButton.frame.origin.x + spaceBetweenButtons, y: buttonsYPosition, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
buttonX.setImage(UIImage(named: "buttonsXImage"), for: UIControlState())
buttonX.tag = 0
buttonX.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
let buttonXRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didDragButton))
buttonX.addGestureRecognizer(buttonXRecognizer)
```

Any ideas what can be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Show some of your code or IB. Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @toddg I've added the code for the scroll view and for the buttons. Please take a look

Comment: Are the buttons at the bottom of the screen? Maybe you're running into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23047708

Comment: @toddg 5 of the buttons responds for taps. Just 2 buttons don't so I don't think it's the problem. Any other idea?

Comment: Maybe your problem is the view that contains your scrollView , you can clip your container view, and see if your two problematics buttons are still there, or you can set border color and width for your scrollView container view

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you! Working :)

Comment: @FS.O6 added as an Answer to avoid keeps this question as unanswered

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you!

Comment: I am glad @FS.O6 , you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the view that contains your `scrollView`, you can clip your container view, and see if your two problematics buttons are still there, or you can set border color and width for your `scrollView` container view

check clipping the view that contains your scrollView

```
self.scrollViewSuperView.clipsToBounds = true
```

or you can setup `scrollViewSuperView` border width and border color

```
self.scrollViewSuperView.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
self.scrollViewSuperView.borderWidth = 1
```

Then adjust your constraints/frames according

I hope this helps