# Swift: Touch not immediately registered for UIButtons located at bottom of UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I run into a strange behaviour I am not able to solve. If I place a UIButton at the bottom of the UIViewController of the Main Storyboard, touching it is not immediately registered. It takes about 0.5 seconds till the touch gets registered. You can see than from standard UIButtons when they change the text color. I don't have this issue with buttons anywhere else in the UIViewController.

All I did is adding a Vertical Stack View with 15 UIButtons to the Main View Controller of a new App. When I execute the App on an iPhone 6 or iPhone 8 (the actual devices), the lowest button behaves differently. Touching it doesn't change the text color immediately, while it does for all the other buttons.

Did anyone experience the same issue? Is there a way to solve this or did I just find a bug in the framework? I'm using Xcode 9.2 and deployment target is iOS 11.2.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `AppDelegate` and try adding:

```
for gesture in self.window.gestureRecognizers {
    gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
}
```

It will stop the system from checking to see if you are trying to open control centre.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Brandon. Unfortunately, that didn't work. However, overriding `func point` as mentioned in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046539](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046539/uibutton-fails-to-properly-register-touch-in-bottom-region-of-iphone-screen) does work.